# Player gets injured every week in Manager Mode

Tags: ios, fifa-12

On Fifa 12 Ipad, one of my players ( N. Wedderburn) got injured one match. It was a Back Strain or something, and it said he would be injured for like 5 weeks. The next match though, it then said he had whiplash and would be out for a week. This then kept happening after every match, but with different injuries and dates each time. Now I haven't been able to play him for 10 matches. How can I stop him from being injured so I can finally play him?

Comment: Have you tried to decrease the level of injury via settings ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem

The problem was that he didn't play because he was injured, but he was still in my starting line-up. When I replaced him the problem was solved!